# Running timers not on the main thread,and create clear external functions

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This is a fundamental question,that may "expose" my mis-understanding of things .

Using some physics engine i am creating my own functions .
Some of them are using a timer (in my case cocos2d timer: `CCSchedulde @selector()` ) . 
My goal is to build some class , that i can use where ever i need to do some action.

Questions :

1. That function has to update some positioning with timer after calling it, but when i put it in other class and create an instance of it , the timer will not run. running it on the main thread seems somehow like not healthy to me. whats the "right" way ?

2.how can i create that function in another class so i can use it like they do with cocos2d engine:

```
id action=[CCActionName ....]  //than i can use action. where is the allocation and initialization?
```

Their way seems much clear than:

```
classA *action=[classA alloc]init];
[action functionName:argument]
```

How can i create my other class to look like their ?

Now i do it like this :

```
ClassA.h
int A1;
int B1;

classA.m
    -(void)initWith:(int)A AndB:(int)B
    {
        A1=A;
        B1=B;
        [run timer function] //COCOS OR NS
    }


    -(void)timer:(cctime)dt   //does not work -its other class and not main thread
    {
        do the action till something .
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers :

1.

When you are trying to use the cocos2d timer on another layer without adding that layer, it wouldn't start the timer (thats the nature of the `CCLayer` to add them .. ) so create NSObject class instead..

2.

I found some structure that i like, i hope that people here will correct me if i am wrong .

So i am creating that `rootClass` . it has some functions (actions) that when executed , he create an instance of another class - `classA` where this one set the timer when initiated :

```
rootclass.m
-(void)doActionWith:(int)a
{
   classA *A=[classA alloc]init];
   [A doActionWith:(int)a];
}

A.m

-(void)doActionWith:(int)a
{
 localV=a;
[start NSTimer];
}

-(void)timer:(NSTimer*)me
{
   use the localV that got its values
   update things till done...
}
```

than, when want to use it , we inherit the `rootClass` than to use the actions from A we don't have to allocate or create instances, we just do :

```
[self doActionWith:a ] // calls the root class that create a NEW instance of an action class A
```

than we can do how many actions we want, without the allocations.
Many actions like that can be added to the rootClass .
Hope it helps , and that its a good attitude .